# IIS 7 URL Rewrite Rule Assistance

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7

I would like to take the following URL

http://MYSERVER/API_Tasks/V1/controller/task.php?taskid=2

and rewrite it to: 
http://MYSERVER/API_Tasks/V1/tasks/2

I have the following rule created but it does not seem to work

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^tasks/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="controller/task.php?taskid={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

original Apache .htaccess rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^tasks/([0-9]+)$ controller/task.php?taskid=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually caused by the rule in IIS being placed on the API_Tasks directory and not the API_Tasks/V1 directory. Adding the URL rule to the V1 fixed the issue.